# Add a key to ListPickerItem

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, key, listpicker, windows-phone-8-sdk

**XAML:**

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="profession" SelectionChanged="ListPicker_SelectionChanged">
    <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value1" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

**How can I add a key to the `ListPickerItem` to be used in the C# code?**

What I want is similar to HTML's `value` attribute for the `option` control.

**Example of what I want:** (C# code, OFC not working..)

```
int a = profession.SelectedItem.Key;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Tag` property.

```xml
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Value1" Tag="1"/>
```

```cs
var a = ((ListPickerItem)profession.SelectedItem).Tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this when your app first loads, then in your MainPage.xaml.cs file, include this in your constructor:

```
public MainPage(){
     InitializeComponent();

     profession.Items.Add("Value2"); // Add this line here
}
```

Otherwise, put this line wherever you need it.

Comment: I don't think you understand, but thank you for your answer. what i'm trying to do is add another data (a numeric key) for each `ListPickerItem` (I wrote just 1 up there to make it shorter). So when I use that `ListPickerItem` in my c# I'll be able to get his key as well. i'll add a not working example above in a sec

Comment: Gotcha. I see you've edited the question to make it much clearer.